# H2GIS deserializing Geometry type causes stack overflow error

Tags: spring, kotlin, h2, r2dbc

My current project uses **PostGIS** for geolocation tools. I used the following converter config so I can serialize a *Point* type.

This works **fine** in production for Postgres with PostGIS - I can save, query and use the model, but as soon as I want to use this in test cases, with H2 and **H2GIS**, I get a stack overflow for *decode*s. More exactly, the `findAll()` on the repository causes the **overflow**, while `save()` seems to work fine.

This is the test I'm trying to run, simply save an entity and get it from the repository

```kotlin
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT, classes = [Application::class])
class ParkingIntegrationTest {
    @Autowired
    lateinit var parkingRepository: ParkingRepository

    @Test
    fun createGetParking() {

        val geometryFactory = GeometryFactory(PrecisionModel(), 4326)
        val coordinate = Coordinate(51.5285262, -0.2664018)
        val point = geometryFactory.createPoint(coordinate)

        runBlocking {
           var parking = parkingRepository.save(
                Parking(
                    null,
                    point,
                ),
            )

            println(parking)

            println(parkingRepository.findAll().toList())
        }
    }
}
```

On running this test the parkingRepository.save() completes, and on the parkingRepository.findAll() I get the following stackTrace:

```
2023-11-04T14:49:04.634+02:00  INFO 18392 --- [    Test worker] edu.myapp.ParkingIntegrationTest         : Started ParkingIntegrationTest in 2.218 seconds (process running for 2.717)
Parking(id=d32deaae-682c-4bd5-a451-7b2ae90861c0, coordinates=POINT (51.5285262 -0.2664018))
2023-11-04T14:49:05.177+02:00  WARN 18392 --- [er @coroutine#1] reactor.core.Exceptions                  : throwIfFatal detected a jvm fatal exception, which is thrown and logged below:

java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
    at io.r2dbc.h2.codecs.AbstractCodec.canDecode(AbstractCodec.java:36) ~[r2dbc-h2-1.0.0.RELEASE.jar:1.0.0.RELEASE]
    at io.r2dbc.h2.codecs.DefaultCodecs.decode(DefaultCodecs.java:56) ~[r2dbc-h2-1.0.0.RELEASE.jar:1.0.0.RELEASE]
    at io.r2dbc.h2.codecs.ParameterCodec.doDecode(ParameterCodec.java:22) ~[r2dbc-h2-1.0.0.RELEASE.jar:1.0.0.RELEASE]
    at io.r2dbc.h2.codecs.ParameterCodec.doDecode(ParameterCodec.java:6) ~[r2dbc-h2-1.0.0.RELEASE.jar:1.0.0.RELEASE]
    at io.r2dbc.h2.codecs.AbstractCodec.decode(AbstractCodec.java:60) ~[r2dbc-h2-1.0.0.RELEASE.jar:1.0.0.RELEASE]
    at io.r2dbc.h2.codecs.DefaultCodecs.decode(DefaultCodecs.java:57) ~[r2dbc-h2-1.0.0.RELEASE.jar:1.0.0.RELEASE]
    at io.r2dbc.h2.codecs.ParameterCodec.doDecode(ParameterCodec.java:22) ~[r2dbc-h2-1.0.0.RELEASE.jar:1.0.0.RELEASE]
    at io.r2dbc.h2.codecs.ParameterCodec.doDecode(ParameterCodec.java:6) ~[r2dbc-h2-1.0.0.RELEASE.jar:1.0.0.RELEASE]
    at io.r2dbc.h2.codecs.AbstractCodec.decode(AbstractCodec.java:60) ~[r2dbc-h2-1.0.0.RELEASE.jar:1.0.0.RELEASE]
    at io.r2dbc.h2.codecs.DefaultCodecs.decode(DefaultCodecs.java:57) ~[r2dbc-h2-1.0.0.RELEASE.jar:1.0.0.RELEASE]
    at io.r2dbc.h2.codecs.ParameterCodec.doDecode(ParameterCodec.java:22) ~[r2dbc-h2-1.0.0.RELEASE.jar:1.0.0.RELEASE]
    at io.r2dbc.h2.codecs.ParameterCodec.doDecode(ParameterCodec.java:6) ~[r2dbc-h2-1.0.0.RELEASE.jar:1.0.0.RELEASE]
    at io.r2dbc.h2.codecs.AbstractCodec.decode(AbstractCodec.java:60) ~[r2dbc-h2-1.0.0.RELEASE.jar:1.0.0.RELEASE]
    at io.r2dbc.h2.codecs.DefaultCodecs.decode(DefaultCodecs.java:57) ~[r2dbc-h2-1.0.0.RELEASE.jar:1.0.0.RELEASE]
    at io.r2dbc.h2.codecs.ParameterCodec.doDecode(ParameterCodec.java:22) ~[r2dbc-h2-1.0.0.RELEASE.jar:1.0.0.RELEASE]
    at io.r2dbc.h2.codecs.ParameterCodec.doDecode(ParameterCodec.java:6) ~[r2dbc-h2-1.0.0.RELEASE.jar:1.0.0.RELEASE]
    at io.r2dbc.h2.codecs.AbstractCodec.decode(AbstractCodec.java:60) ~[r2dbc-h2-1.0.0.RELEASE.jar:1.0.0.RELEASE]
...
```

And this repeats until my console fills up.

These are my implementations of the reader/reader

```kotlin
import org.locationtech.jts.geom.GeometryFactory
import org.locationtech.jts.geom.Point
import org.locationtech.jts.geom.PrecisionModel
import org.locationtech.jts.io.WKBReader
import org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter
import org.springframework.data.convert.ReadingConverter

@ReadingConverter
class ToPointConverter : Converter<String, Point> {
    private val geometryFactory = GeometryFactory(PrecisionModel(), 4326)
    private val reader = WKBReader(geometryFactory)
    override fun convert(source: String): Point? {
        return reader.read(source.chunked(2).map { it.toInt(16).toByte() }.toByteArray()) as Point?
    }
}
```

```kotlin
import org.locationtech.jts.geom.Point
import org.locationtech.jts.io.WKBWriter
import org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter
import org.springframework.data.convert.WritingConverter

@WritingConverter
class PointToWkbConverter : Converter<Point, ByteArray> {
    private val writer = WKBWriter(2, true)
    override fun convert(source: Point): ByteArray? {
        return writer.write(source)
    }
}
```

The repository is a simple CrudRepository

```kotlin
interface ParkingRepository : CoroutineCrudRepository<Parking, UUID>
```

Data class

```kotlin
@Table(name = "parking")
data class Parking(
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid")
    val id: UUID? = null,

    val coordinates: Point,
)
```

My gradle config and dependencies used

```kotlin
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

plugins {
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "3.1.2"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.1.2"
    id("org.jlleitschuh.gradle.ktlint") version "11.5.0"
    id("org.liquibase.gradle") version "2.0.4"

    kotlin("jvm") version "1.8.22"
    kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.8.22"
    kotlin("kapt") version "1.9.10"
}

group = "h2.test"

java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-r2dbc")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")
    implementation("io.projectreactor.kotlin:reactor-kotlin-extensions")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-reactor")
    implementation("org.liquibase:liquibase-core:4.23.0")
    implementation("org.postgresql:r2dbc-postgresql:1.0.0.RELEASE")
    implementation("org.springframework:spring-jdbc:6.0.11")
    implementation("com.auth0:java-jwt:4.4.0")
    implementation("org.apache.httpcomponents.client5:httpclient5:5.2.1")
    implementation("org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-starter-webflux-ui:2.2.0")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:3.1.2")
    implementation("org.locationtech.jts:jts-core:1.19.0")
    implementation("org.orbisgis:h2gis:2.2.0")

    annotationProcessor("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor:3.1.2")

    runtimeOnly("org.postgresql:postgresql")
    runtimeOnly("org.postgresql:r2dbc-postgresql")

    testImplementation("io.mockk:mockk:1.13.5")
    testImplementation("io.r2dbc:r2dbc-h2:1.0.0.RELEASE")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
    testImplementation("io.projectreactor:reactor-test")
}

tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs += "-Xjsr305=strict"
        jvmTarget = "17"
    }
}

tasks.withType<Test> {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```